# Is there a "fancy" Ruby way to check whether a local variable is both defined and evaluates to true without using ands and ors?

Tags: ruby

This is quite a quick question. I currently use*

```
do_this if (testvar ||= false)
```

Which works just fine.

But this approach unnerves me because while fast, it does not short-circuit like `defined?(testvar) && testvar` does, and it instantiates and assigns a value to a local variable that is subsequently never used, which seems inefficient.

I enjoy the very reasonable fact that instance variables are nil before assignment, but I'd like for the situation to be just as easy for local variables.

**EDIT:** * – that's a huge lie. I don't know why I said that. I don't use `testvar ||= false`. That would be silly. What I have used, however, is `testvar rescue false`, which doesn't have nearly as many ugly side effects (does it?).

Comment: What's wrong with `defined?(testvar) && testvar`? That shows what you want pretty clearly.

Comment: Also I'd add that you should always know whether a local variable is defined before you look at its value. Perhaps if you showed a little more code we could help you refactor your entire function to be cleaner.

Comment: I agree with Ben Alpert.  The other expression states its intention much clearer while yours is cryptic in the sense that your readers will wonder if there was a need in subsequent code that requires `testvar` set.

Comment: By using code like displayed in the example, you're reacting to Ruby trying to tell you you're doing something wrong, rather than fix the problem that is causing the error.

Comment: Using an inline `rescue` is marginally acceptable this way but could lead to very hard to find bugs if an exception is raised but masked by the rescue statement. Again, doing this is an attempt to hide the error code displayed by Ruby, rather than fix the code causing it to be raised.

Comment: Regarding rescue: Matz himself has stated that Exceptions are not very performance friendly since they are 'exceptional' so the performance shouldn't make much difference. In the shorthand `foo rescue false` your incurring all that overhead during normal operation. That's a good reason not to start making a habit of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about a "fancy" way but there's an explicit way, which is sometimes better than fancy, IMHO.

```
do_this if defined? testvar and testvar
```

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
do_this unless testvar.nil?
```

Comment: This isn't right because it throws a NameError if `testvar` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to using this with instance variables instead of local variables. Changing testvar to @testvar would fix that.